# How to get the image upload progress using node.js and use it in my iphone app

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, node.js

I don't know how to get the current uploading progress using node.js, and don't know how to send the progress values to my iphone client app. I currently have a code like this, but it only save the image file and save the image filename to the db.

```
app.post('/event', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
        var newPath = __dirname + '/uploads/' + req.files.displayImage.name;
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                var pic = req.files.displayImage.name;
                connection.query('INSERT INTO Event SET ?', {pic: pic}, function (error, result) {
                    if (error) {
                        res.send(error, 400);
                    } else {
                        res.send({insertId: result.insertId}, 200);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems like two questions: how to return the progress, and how to use it. While I can help you with the first, you will probably want to open another question for the latter as you are not providing any information on how you plan to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Like everything else in node, there is a node module (named [node-upload-progress](https://github.com/phstc/node-upload-progress)) for that. Though I haven't personally used it, it seems pretty solid. Since you seem to be using `Express`, I will do the same in my example:

First, you need to set up the uploadHandler:

```
var app = express();
var uploadHandler = require('node-upload-progress');
uploadHandler.configure(function() {
    return this.uploadDir = "" + __dirname + "/uploads";
});

app.post('/event', function (req, res) {
    return uploadHandler.progress(req, res);
});
```

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/phstc/node-upload-progress/blob/master/lib/node-upload-progress.js#L68), it seems that this will return a 200 status code, with the upload data in a json object.

As for an example of what you can use it for, check this [html file](https://github.com/phstc/node-upload-progress/blob/master/examples/express/views/index.html#L17), from which I am posting the below snippet. This snippet shows how you can periodically check for the progress status using an ajax call from the client side.

```
uploadIntervalID = setInterval(function(){
      $.get('/progress?X-Progress-ID=' + xProgressID, function(data){
            if(data.status === 'done'){
                clearInterval(uploadIntervalID);
            }
            updateUploadStatus(data);
      }).error(function(){clearInterval(uploadIntervalID)});
 }, 250);
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this module. I will check it out.